# URL field inherited despite separate cross reference item

Tags: bibtex, urls

The following code produces a list of references that contains the URL three times. I use crossreferencing to save space. Is there a way to get rid of the URL in the entries that refere to a main entry?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\citet{Flickinger2008a,VanEynde2008a}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@inproceedings{Flickinger2008a,
        Author = {Daniel P. Flickinger},
        Crossref = {Mueller2008a-ed},
        Title = {Transparent Heads}}


@inproceedings{VanEynde2008a,
        Author = {Frank {Van Eynde}},
        Crossref = {Mueller2008a-ed},
        Pages = {253--273},
        Title = {Predicate Complements}}


@proceedings{Mueller2008a-ed,
        Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar},
        Editor = {Stefan M{\"u}ller},
        Title = {Proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar},
        Url = {http://cslipublications.stanford.edu/HPSG/9/},
        Year = {2008}}
```

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a design decision in the `plainnat` style. I get no URL for the `@inproceedings` entries if I modify `plainnat.bst` to have the following `inproceedings` function:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
          publisher output
          format.date "year" output.check
        }
        { address output.nonnull
          format.date "year" output.check
          new.sentence
          organization output
          publisher output
        }  
      if$
      format.isbn output
      format.doi output
      format.url output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
%  format.isbn output
%  format.doi output
%  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

The commented out lines are responsible for adding the `isbn`, `doi` and `url` fields and have been moved in the "false" branch of the test `crossref missing$`, so that `@inproceedings` entries without a `crossref` field will get the URL.

As usual, you should make a copy of `plainnat.bst` under a new name, say `myplainnat.bst`. Similar modifications should be made to the `inbook` and `incollection` functions.

Comment: @StefanMüller When a field is declared for an entry, in this case `url`, it is inherited from the entry referred to with `crossref`, if missing. This is a rule of BibTeX. So either you define a new field type, say `urlhere` and update the relevant functions, or there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 3):

It strikes me that the `url` fields of the three entries should not all be the same. In particular, the entries `Flickinger2008a` and `VanEynde2008a` should really be given their own separate `url` fields. I.e., the entry `Flickinger2008a` might be given the field

```
url = {http://cslipublications.stanford.edu/HPSG/9/Flickinger.pdf},
```

and the entry `VanEynde2008a` might be given the field

```
url = {http://cslipublications.stanford.edu/HPSG/9/vaneynde.pdf},
```

The chief reason for providing separate `url` fields is that the URLs of the entries of type `@inproceedings` are pdf files, whereas the URL of the `@proceedings`-type entry is a web page. By providing separate URLs, you make it easy (or easier) on the readers to obtain just the publication(s) they want, rather than making them go first to a website and then scroll around for a while until they manage to find the paper they're interested in.

**Addendum**, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP: If you do *not* want to have the "child" entries (of type `@inproceedings`) "inherit" the value of the `url` field from the "parent" entry (of type `@proceedings`) at all, you could simply set a blank value for the corresponding `url` fields, i.e., you could set

```
url = {},
```

for both of the "child" entries.